# Relating the order of a multiplicative character to the image of the character

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

Let $F_{p} = \mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z}$ and $\chi$ be a multiplicative character on $F_{p}$ of order $k$, i.e. $\underbrace{\chi \chi \cdots \chi}_{k\text{-times}} = \chi_{0}$ where $\chi_{0}$ is the trivial character. After computing several examples by hand, it seems that $Im(\chi)$ is isomorphic to the $k$th roots of unity, which we will denote $\Gamma_{k}$, but I am having a hard time proving this.

It is easy to see that $Im(\chi) \subseteq \Gamma_{k}$ because for any $a \in F_{p}$, we have $$\underbrace{\chi(a) \chi(a) \cdots \chi(a)}_{k\text{-times}} = \chi^k(a) = \chi_{0}(a) = 1. $$
However given an arbitrary $z \in \Gamma_{n}$, how can one show that $z \in Im(\chi)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbb{F}_p^\times$ is cyclic and a multiplicative character $\chi$ is determined by where it sends a chosen generator: if the generator is sent to an element of order $k$, then $\chi$ and its image will have order $k$. Indeed, the generator can be sent to any element of order dividing $|\mathbb{F}_p^\times|=p-1$, so this not only establishes what order $\chi$ can have in the dual group, it sets up a bijection between the multiplicative characters $\chi$ and $(p-1)$st roots of unity. (The bijection depends on choice of generator though.)